# Electron file outside root

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm writing an application with electron and server side node js. Now I have certain files that would be the same between both, I was thinking I could make something like a "shared" folder for shared modules.

SO: Is electron including those (or electron packager or whatever (you can happily suggest something)) including such files in the compiled version? I'm also wondering if I could have global libraries that will "copy" themselves into the compiled version?

Many thanks, Elias :)

Comment: Can you add some code snippets of your current environment?

Comment: well there is no environment yet but I thought: root -> server / client. Or what exactly to you mean?

Comment: In Electron you can write server AND client side on the same application. Take a look at this https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express

Comment: Yes sure, but do I really want my server files being included into the client application? It doesn't seem to be that easy. I will just create two files and keep them both the same =) thanks anyway

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi I have a similar question, I didn't know this question existed. I have explained the problem in detail here [My Question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546945/packaged-electron-app-not-detecting-not-packaging-node-js-files-outside-the-dire)

Comment: What do you think about my previous comment? Or take a look also to this repo https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron